# USB camera compatibility

Tags: raspbian, usb, webcam, motion

When I connect my camera to Pi and run the command `lsusb`, I get this output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device  003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID  2717:0388   
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 093a:2628 Pixart Imaging, Inc.
```

Is my camera compatible?

If I remove the camera and run the same command, this line:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 093a:2628 Pixart Imaging, Inc.
```

will be removed. I tried motion. I couldn't stream. I don't know if the problem is with `motion.conf` or the camera.

Comment: you could check [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Webcams) to see a list of compatible cameras.

Comment: start with a search for the usb ID and compatibility with Linux in general https://www.google.com/?q=093a:2628+linux From a cursory glance it looks like it is quite an old device.

Comment: @VishaalDevanaboyina Not included in that list

Comment: @rob If it works with linux then it should work with raspberry pi?

Comment: @DushyanthShenoy - Ok, then there is a chance it isn't compatible, but that list is not an exhaustive one and thus shouldn't be relied on completely.  As rob mentions checking if it's Linux compatible is a good start as well.

Comment: @DushyanthShenoy If there exists an open source driver for the device then there is a  good chance you could get it working with the Pi(might be hard work though), the problem arises if the driver is binary and not compatible with the Pi's ARM processor. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does my camera is compatible ?

No, it just means it's been recognized; this doesn't require any driver.

However, this device ID is listed in the source for the `gspca_pac7302` driver.  With the device plugged in, try `lsmod | grep gspca` and see if it is listed.  If not,

```
sudo modprobe gspca_pac7302
```

Answer (score 1):

As above, `lsusb` only shows is connected, not that a driver is installed.

For testing, I'd try fswebcam before motion:

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam

fswebcam image.jpg
```

Comment: if you get trouble with palette, check here : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27341/unable-to-find-a-compatible-palette-format

Answer (score 0):

Is this thread still alive?
Got a new (rather used) USB cam:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb -s:005
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 093a:2600 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Typhoon Easycam USB 330K (newer)/Typhoon Easycam USB 2.0 VGA 1.3M/Sansun SN-508

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ fswebcam
--- Opening /dev/video0...
stat: No such file or directory

Please advice!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/122377)